# Pandas dataframe remove last "\" from Parent and Child columns

Tags: python, regex, pandas, dataframe

I have a pandas data frame and am looking to remove everything before and the last `\` so that all that is left is the executable.  This is what I would like to achieve:  `C:\Windows\System32\services.exe` to just `services.exe`

```
    Parent                              Child                           PID     PID System_Or_User
0   C:\Windows\System32\services.exe    C:\Windows\System32\svchost.exe 10396   752 System
1   C:\Windows\System32\services.exe    C:\Windows\System32\svchost.exe 11688   752 System
2   C:\Windows\System32\services.exe    C:\Windows\System32\svchost.exe 11624   752 System
```

I have tried a few things like this but can't seem to get it right maybe because of the `\` used in windows and python not liking it:

```
PID['Parent'] = PID['Parent'].apply(lambda x: x[0].split('\ ')[-1])

PID['Parent'] = PID['Parent'].apply(lambda x: x[0].split(' \ ')[+1])
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [`str.split`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.str.split.html) by escape `\` with indexing - select last value of `list`s:

```
PID['Parent'] = PID['Parent'].str.split('\\').str[-1]
PID['Child'] = PID['Child'].str.split('\\').str[-1]
```

Another similar idea - use [`str.rsplit`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.str.rsplit.html) with `n=1` for split by last `\` for better performance:

```
PID['Parent'] = PID['Parent'].str.rsplit('\\', n=1).str[-1]
PID['Child'] = PID['Child'].str.rsplit('\\', n=1).str[-1]
```

**Detail**:

```
print (PID['Parent'].str.rsplit('\\', n=1))
0    [C:\Windows\System32, services.exe]
1    [C:\Windows\System32, services.exe]
2    [C:\Windows\System32, services.exe]
Name: Parent, dtype: object
```

---

```
print (PID)
         Parent        Child    PID PID System_Or_User
0  services.exe  svchost.exe  10396         752 System
1  services.exe  svchost.exe  11688         752 System
2  services.exe  svchost.exe  11624         752 System
```

Answer (score 3):

Use `str.split` and `str.get`, with escaping the backslash by typing `\\`

```
df.Parent.str.split('\\').str.get(-1)

0    services.exe
1    services.exe
2    services.exe
Name: Parent, dtype: object
```

Answer (score 3):

You're dealing with paths. If you want a cross platform solution, I recommend leaving the splitting to `os.path`.

This should be as fast as (or faster than) the `str.` methods.

```
import os
df['Parent'] = [os.path.basename(v) for v in df['Parent']]
df['Child'] = [os.path.basename(v) for v in df['Child']]
```

Alternatively, you may use `os.path.split`.

```
df['Parent'] = [os.path.split(v)[-1] for v in df['Parent']]
df['Child'] = [os.path.split(v)[-1] for v in df['Child']]
```

Answer (score 2):

Or maybe `str.replace`

```
df.Parent.str.replace(r"C:\\Windows\\System32\\","")
Out[25]: 
0    services.exe
1    services.exe
2    services.exe
Name: Parent, dtype: object
```